# cannot increment value when using threadpool in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using the class that was provided by [Python Thread Pool (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/) in order to simulate thread pooling. I am trying to increment the value `counter` in function `test`. The problem is that it is remaining `0`. I used `lock` that was explained in [Is this simple python code thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717393/is-this-simple-python-code-thread-safe) but still it's not working.

---

## Source code

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

class Worker(Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try: func(*args, **kargs)
            except Exception, e: print e
            self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()

def exp1_thread(counter):
  with lock:
    print counter
    counter = counter + 1

def test():
  # 1) Init a Thread pool with the desired number of threads
  pool = ThreadPool(6)
  counter = 0
  for i in range(0, 10):
    pool.add_task(exp1_thread,counter)
  
   # 3) Wait for completion
  pool.wait_completion()
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  test()
```

---

## output

```
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
counter 0
```

---

Comment: Well first of all, `counter` is a local variable inside `test()`, you'd need to put it say at the top of your script and make it global. Or you'd need to update your value some how by calling a function in the thread and fetch the value.

Comment: oh ok it worked lol but I don't know why should I declare it as a global variable?

Comment: Because if you don't declare it as a global variable, the variable will not be in a shared memory space, it will be "protected" in the main thread object. You could in theory do `from threading import enumerate as tenum` and access the main thread object and it's variables and THEN update that variable. It's not really recommended to do any of this, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting all zeros is because the integer value counter is passed by value to the threads. Each thread receives a copy of the counter and then goes to town.

You can fix this by finding a way to pass the value by reference.

Option 1. Define counter as a list you pass around:

```
def exp1_thread(counter):
    with lock:
        print counter[0]
        counter[0] = counter[0] + 1

def test():
    # 1) Init a Thread pool with the desired number of threads
    pool = ThreadPool(6)
    counter = [0]
    for i in range(0, 10):
        pool.add_task(exp1_thread, counter)

    # 3) Wait for completion
    pool.wait_completion()
```

Option 2. Create an object you pass around.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, initial_count):
        self.count = initial_count

def exp1_thread(counter):
    with lock:
        print counter.count
        counter.count = counter.count + 1

def test():
    # 1) Init a Thread pool with the desired number of threads
    pool = ThreadPool(6)
    counter = Counter(0)
    for i in range(0, 10):
        pool.add_task(exp1_thread, counter)

    # 3) Wait for completion
    pool.wait_completion()
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with threading. The actual reason is that `int` is immutable in Python. 
A function that just increments an `int` would not have the desired effect.

```
def inc(x):
    x +=1
y = 0
inc(y)
print y  # 0
```

If you want to increment the number you can store it in a mutable datatype (such as a `list` or `dict`) and manipulate the list.

Comment: I saw the earlier explanations. the are great I didn't know what is immutable. it was a little confusing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

`int` work differently from `dictionaries`, I'm sure someone well versed in Python logic can explain the difference. This is the logic I usually use and it works. As I just realized it's because you're passing the object (dict, list etc) and not the value itself.

Either declare your variables as globals (but be careful) or use say a dictionary with individual key slots for the different threads and sum them up at the end.

```
from threading import *
from time import sleep

myMap = {'counter' : 0}

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, counterMap):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.counterMap = counterMap
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.counterMap['counter'] += 1

worker(myMap)
sleep(0.2)
worker(myMap)

sleep(0.2)
print(myMap)
```

Comment: Sorry for the question. If i want to use a list inside a thread, should It also be a global variable?

Comment: @HaniGoc No that is not needed. it appears to be working if passed as an argument.