# how to instantiate pybind11::array_t in separate thread

Tags: pybind11

In pybind11-wrapped c++, called from python, I can do this:

`py::array_t<double> t1 = py::array_t<double>(3);`

But: if I do that in a separate thread, it crashes with a segmentation fault (actually it seems to crash when t1 goes out of scope or gets destructed).

I can fix this by doing

```
PyGILState_STATE gstate;
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

pybind11::array_t<double> t1 = pybind11::array_t<double>(3)

PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

So obviously there is some GIL-dependent stuff in pybind11::array_t. Is it necessarily so? Do I have to acquire the GIL in order to instantiate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GIL is required.

When you create a python object you are interacting with python interpreter. At some point of the process you need to acquire GIL to do it [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006337/python-c-api-is-it-thread-safe).

That said, creation of `pybind11::array_t` might have expensive part which doesn't require GIL and could be done in another thread. For example you may allocate and initialize raw data and pass it to `pybind11::array_t` constructor to quickly create object with GIL.